# react-native, JSI synchronous call and debugging

Tags: react-native, remote-debugging, flipper

I need to use a library that makes synchronous JSI calls in my react-native application.
The problem is that I need to debug my code.... and remote debugging is not possible when synchronous call exists. Since debugging is a relative common concept I looked for solution. The only one that apparently exist is to use Flipper.

But I have 2 problems
1 - It is being deprecated by react-native!
2 - I did not manage to get it to work. Because of the above I am reluctant at spending time on it

So,is there some alternatives?

Comment: take a look at Detox